# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule removing double slash unintentionally

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite rule which passes a simple string (attr '`mode`') and a url (attr `target_url`) with format: http://dummypage.com/

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/.]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?mode=$1&target_url=$2
```

converting

```
mydomain.com/test/stringparam/http://dummypage.com/
```

to

```
mydomain.com/index.php?mode=stringparam&target_url=http:/dummypage.com/
```

notice that it changed http://dummypage.com/ to http:/dummypage.com/,
why does it remove double slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match this kind of URI using `RewriteRule`. Use `THE_REQUEST` variable to match it. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+test/([^/]+)/([^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?mode=%1&target_url=%2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: nice, thanks, tho that's returning e500 internal server error, any idea why ?

Comment: better, returning 404 now :)

Comment: This gets internally redirected to `/index.php?mode=stringparam&target_url=http://dummypage.com/` Can you check and this if `/index.php?mode=stringparam&target_url=http://dummypage.com/` URL works for you directly?

Comment: yep,
`mydomain.com/index.php?mode=stringparam&target_url=http://dummypage.com/`

 working fine

Comment: Very strange, I have already tested it. Can you add `R` for testing to make it `[L,QSA,R,NE]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38902/discussion-between-enoque-duarte-and-anubhava)

Comment: May I know your Apache version? and your OS?

Comment: @anubhava CentOS5, apache v. 2.2.24

Comment: ok thanks. If you remember you got 500 error at the beginning (it was due to looping) so definitely rule condition was working at that time. However now even if you comment 1st `RewriteCond` you still get 404, weird